# Откуда подставляются категории в коде?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
class SliderSidebar extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const { actions } = this.props;
        actions.fetchListIfNeeded();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let $el = $(findDOMNode(this));
        if ($el.height() > 514) {
            $el.addClass('short');
        }
    }

    handleShowMore() {
        $(findDOMNode(this)).removeClass('short');
    }

    render() {
        const { loading, received, objects } = this.props;

        if (loading || !received) {
            return null;
        }

        let data = objects;
        let dl_count = 0;
        let dl = data.map(item => {
            dl_count = dl_count + item.items.length;
            return item.items.length;
        });

        let dlc = dl.map(item => item / dl_count * 100);

        if (dlc.length == 2) {
            if (dlc[0] > 60) {
                dlc[0] = 60;
            }
            if (dlc[1] < 40) {
                dlc[1] = 40;
            }
        }

        let menuNodes = data.map((item, i) => {
            let nodes = item.items.map(model => (
                    <li key={'ss' + model.id}>
                        <Link to="CatalogList" params={{url: model.url}}>
                            {model.name}
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ));

            return (
                <div key={'ssr' + item.id} style={{height: dlc[i] + '%'}} className="root-menu">
                    <p><strong>{item.name}</strong></p>

                    <div className="bottom">
                        <div className="show_more">
                            <span className="text" onClick={this.handleShowMore.bind(this)}>
                                Смотреть все категории
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        {i != data.length - 1 ? <hr/> : null}
                    </div>

                    <ul className="sidebar-menu">{nodes}</ul>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return <div className="sidebar index short">{menuNodes}</div>;
    }
}

export default connect(state => state.category, dispatch => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    };
})(SliderSidebar);
```

Есть такая конструкция, я не знаю реакт, поэтому прошу подсказать откуда подставляются категории?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду? Вопрос не понятен

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach мне нужно изменить название одной из категорий, нашел этот код и если я правильно понимаю он рендерит как раз тот список с категориями, но я не могу понять откуда он берет названия категорий, понятно объяснил?

Comment: Понял, можно код в текстовом виде?

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach именно этот кусок? (может нужно что-то ещё) сейчас отредактирую тему

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach вставил полностью весь код файла sidebar,jsx, ну там ещё импорты вверху, но они вряд ли помогут чем то

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach не сможете объяснить?

Answer (score 0):

```html
class SliderSidebar extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
      const { actions } = this.props;
      actions.fetchListIfNeeded();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      let $el = $(findDOMNode(this));
      if ($el.height() > 514) {
          $el.addClass('short');
      }
  }

  handleShowMore() {
      $(findDOMNode(this)).removeClass('short');
  }

  render() {
      const { loading, received, objects } = this.props; // objects приходит сверху вместе с props

      if (loading || !received) {
          return null;
      }

      let data = objects; // objects присваивается в data
      let dl_count = 0;
      let dl = data.map(item => {
          dl_count = dl_count + item.items.length;
          return item.items.length;
      });

      let dlc = dl.map(item => item / dl_count * 100);

      if (dlc.length == 2) {
          if (dlc[0] > 60) {
              dlc[0] = 60;
          }
          if (dlc[1] < 40) {
              dlc[1] = 40;
          }
      }
      /**
       * массив data перебирается с помощью метода .map()
       * тоесть item это элемент массива
       **/ 
      let menuNodes = data.map((item, i) => {

          /**
           * в свою очередь item является тоже массивом и перебирается с помощью метода .map()
           * и здесь model это элемент массива, который является объектом примерно такого вида:
           * {
           *    id: 'some_id',
           *    url: 'some_url',
           *    name: 'Category Name'
           * }
           **/ 
          let nodes = item.items.map(model => (
                  // ниже id из объекта ставится как ключ
                  <li key={'ss' + model.id}> 
                      {/* ниже url из объекта ставится как параметр для <Link /> */}
                      <Link to="CatalogList" params={{url: model.url}}>
                          {/* ниже name из объекта ставится как контент для <Link />, по идее это то что Вы ищете */}
                          {model.name}
                      </Link>
                  </li>
              ));

          return (
              <div key={'ssr' + item.id} style={{height: dlc[i] + '%'}} className="root-menu">
                  <p><strong>{item.name}</strong></p>

                  <div className="bottom">
                      <div className="show_more">
                          <span className="text" onClick={this.handleShowMore.bind(this)}>
                              Смотреть все категории
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      {i != data.length - 1 ? <hr/> : null}
                  </div>

                  <ul className="sidebar-menu">{nodes}</ul>
              </div>
          );
      });

      return <div className="sidebar index short">{menuNodes}</div>;
  }
}

export default connect(state => state.category, dispatch => {
  return {
      actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
  };
})(SliderSidebar);
```

Если вопрос "откуда реакт берет значение названия для категории?" то ответ:

Из `objects`, которые передаются в компонент как `props`, как то так:

```
<SliderSidebar
  objects={some_data}
/>
```

и `some_data` при этом является массивом примерно такой структуры:

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 'some_id',
      url: 'some_url',
      name: 'Category Name'
    },
    {
      id: 'some_id',
      url: 'some_url',
      name: 'Category Name'
    },
    {
      id: 'some_id',
      url: 'some_url',
      name: 'Category Name'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 'some_id',
      url: 'some_url',
      name: 'Category Name'
    },
    {
      id: 'some_id',
      url: 'some_url',
      name: 'Category Name'
    },
    {
      id: 'some_id',
      url: 'some_url',
      name: 'Category Name'
    }
  ]
]
```

Если вопрос "в каком месте я могу заменить название категории на какое-то другое, если я не могу изменить исходные данные?", то ответ:

В этой строке:
`{model.name}`

Comment: Окей отличное объяснение я примерно так и думал, теперь вопрос как отловить массив data откуда приходит, точнее откуда приходит objects

Comment: похоже я нашел откуда берется objects, может у вас есть телеграм, вы мне очень бы помогли

Comment: Извините, но это __out of scope__